# Twitter bootstrap dropdown menu doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I trying to use this menu [Bootstrap Collapsible Side Menu](http://s.bootply.com/render/3NqsdCpjiz#) but something doesn't work properly. There is `+` sign and `-` for open and close. When I open first menu `+` become `-` as must be but when I click on second menu first must close and `-` must become `+`. I hope you get what I mean. This doesn't work properly. Also when I click on second menu the icon that is front of the name become `-` also.

I've tried to recreate this menu in jsfiddle but doesn't work there. Doesn't open the menu but you can see what happen with `+` and `-` signs. If you click on both links they are with `-`.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acidrat/BP6Wh/2/). I didn't work with `jsfiddle` before.

Comment: By how an accordion works, when you open one item up the others will close. So what you need to do is switch all items but the open one to `-`. So for some element `i` from `1` to `n`, you need to force all other classes to `fa-minus`: `1 , .. , i-1 , i+1 , .. , n`

Comment: That's make some sense but I don't really know how to do it in javascript. Any help is appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just forgot to load jquery, or you are loading it after bootstrap. It works fine if you load it properly.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acidrat/BP6Wh/2/

Check you browser console for error messages.

**EDIT**

Ok, now i get it. You will have to work with Bootstrap collapse events that are triggered after collapsing.

```
 $('#menu-bar').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
             var currentlySelectedElement = $(this).find('.collapse.in');
             var targetAnchor = $('[data-target="#' + currentlySelectedElement.attr('id') + '"]');
             $('[data-target="#' + currentlySelectedElement.attr('id') + '"]').find("i.fa-plus").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
         });

         $('#menu-bar').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
             var currentlyCollapsedElements = $(this).find('.collapsed');
             currentlyCollapsedElements.each(function () {
                 $(this).find('i.fa-minus').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
             });

         });
```

Here the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acidrat/BP6Wh/5/

Comment: Ah my mistake for `jquery`. Anyway, now you can see what I mean. When you open `Example Pages` it's `-` and if you click on `Forms` is closed but still `-`. Must be `+` and on `Forms` must be `-`. Also the icon in front of `Forms` become `-`.

Comment: Ok, this is nice and working on `jsfiddle` but doesn't work on my local. The problem is tha `+` doesn't change on `-` when I click on menu. Any idea what can be the problem? I have included `bootstrap.min.css`, `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`, `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js`, `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js`, `bootstrap.min.js`. Javascript is in my `<head>`.

Comment: Try loading jquery before bootstrap maybe and check element id 'menu-bar'

Comment: I've tried.. It's very strange. For sure is something on my side (localhost) becaus on `jsfiddle` is working but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Could you check your browser console for errors? Ctrl+shift+i on chrome

Comment: `GET http://localhost/menu/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 404 (Not Found)`, `GET http://localhost/menu/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 (Not Found)` and `http://localhost/menu/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg 404 (Not Found)`. There is no more errors

Comment: I've put missing fonts and now there is nothing in console output

Comment: Did you chane your menu by adding data-target as seen in my fiddle?

Comment: Yes, it is like this now `<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" data-parent="#menu-bar" href="#">`

Comment: Ok, try to add console.log(targetAnchor); after var targetAnchor... , look into console and post it here

Comment: I whatch console while I click on menus and this appear. Since I'm not into javascript I don't know if is ok or not `[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "[data-target="#undefined"]", jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…]
 `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54616/discussion-between-timur-and-goro).